# Play! 2.0 Scala - Accessing global object

Tags: scala, global, sbt, playframework-2.0

I've declared an object which gets instantiated on application start. I want to access it inside a controller, which is part of a plugin. I want to be able to use that plugin, but I can't seem to get past the first part -- finding the `MyWebsocketConnection` object. None of the examples show how to do this. I don't want to inject into the controller because I'm writing a plugin (I saw static examples of how to do that somewhere).

`Global.scala`, plugin application \app\Global.scala

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  object MyWebsocketConnection {
    val logger = // return something that gets instantiated once, like websocket object for logging to ui
  }

  class MyWebsocketConnection {
    import MyWebsocketConnection.logger
  }

  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    Logger.info("Application has started...");
  }

}
```

My custom logging plugin controller:

`MyLogger.Scala`, plugin application \app\controllers\MyLogger.scala

```
object MyLogger {

  def info(message: String) = {
    // THIS CAN'T BE FOUND ?
    // MyWebsocketConnection.logger.send(message)
  }

}
```

So, from the Play! 2.0 app that references the plugin, I would (probably) do something like below, but I can't even get past the part before this:

`MyFutureController.scala`, another Play! application \app\controllers\MyFutureController.scala

```
object MyFutureController extends Controller {
  def someRandomMethod = Action {
    // Custom logging
    MyLogger.info("Here's my log message!");
    Ok("This documentation stinks!")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is also workaround #3: move your Global class to a package and specify its fully qualified name in application.conf file, like so:

> global= my.packaged.Global

Comment: The default is `application.global=...`. You're right it should be `global=...` without the `application`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your `Global` objects resides in default package. And in Java, classes from default package can't be referenced from other packages, they are accessible only within the same package (default).

I see two workarounds of this problem.

1. Move `MyWebsocketConnection` to some named package (say `config`) so it can be accessible in your application.

   ```
   object MyLogger {
     def info(message: String) = {
     config.MyWebsocketConnection.logger.send(message)
     }
   }
   ```
2. Move your whole application into single package (but it is a lot of pain)

   ```
   foo
     |--controllers
     |--models
     |--views
     |--Global.scala
   ```

   Then `Global` object will resides in `foo` package and will be accessible within application.