# Best way to define globals in a Play! 2.0 application

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

In Play! 2.0, one can use `Global` as documented [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaGlobal). `Global` needs to be in the default (empty) package.

I also need globals in my application, and some of them need to be available to the methods in `Global`. Thus, I put them in Global.scala like so:

```
package object globals {
  lazy val foo = Play.maybeApplication.flatMap(_.configuration.getString("foo")).getOrElse("default_value_of_foo")
}
```

And then I use it in my controllers like this:

```
globals.foo
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is more about general software design than it is about Play Framework. If you truly need a bunch of random properties why not create your own object?

```
object Configuration {
    val timeout = Play.maybeApplication.flatMap(
                      _.configuration.getString("timeout")
                      ).getOrElse(0))
}
```

But usually the values belong to some other logical entity that is being configured.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems using Global as a singleton for my app. I think you will have some problems too to access the singleton from your controllers (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10440864/595223)).

But you can create your own singleton in one of your packages and access it as you plan to do.